# Load all project from folder one by one

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

let me give the idea of the scenario.

```
- Go to a specific folder ( It has 20 projects.)
- Load all projects one by one and execute one rcptt step.
```

So, what i am doing is :

```
loop [val index0] { // i used hard code here. give better suggestion.

    //method to go to that folder

    if [$index| lt 20] {
        //execute a procedure
    }
        recur [$index| plus 1]
    }
```

but this is not happening.

need experts suggestion related this things.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to load projects with ECL code? Why don't you use a Workspace context instead?

Comment: Creating ecl context for all project (20+) does not make sense to me. The project list is growing day by day may be there are 23 proj in the next day.

I just want to make sure that all proj are passed only for a specific small functionality.

Comment: @AdamHorvath i am also facing problem related the for loop. Its also not working for me .... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ECL recorder to do this. Record with the AUT how you would import all projects of a directory by hand:

```
File->Import...
    Existing Projects >
        Select root directory;
        Select All,
        Finish.
```

From the generated ECL script you can extract the literal of the selected directory and turn it into a produce with a path parameter.

I don't think it's necessary to write a loop (or any code at all) for that, given the Select All button of the Import dialog.